# Ping tester equivalent software in ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

Can anyone recommend a equivalent software for ping tester?

[image]

Comment: The screenshot is quite hard to read. What features are you looking for specifically, which are not available in the command-line tools ping and hping?

Comment: First of all i need the time stamp for all ping reports. And then i want to scan a group of ip list which produces a single output.

Comment: I wonder if `nmap` (with the right options) is what you're after? Take a look [here](http://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html). Ctrl+F for 'timestamps' to see if it's suitable.

Comment: Have you tried [man ping](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ping8.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there's the *Network Tools:*

[image]

On Unity, open the Dash and type "Network Tools", in Gnome it's in *System → Administration → Network Tools*.

Comment: It has no timestamps as requested on comments.

Comment: Hi @stefano it would be better if i get the time stamp like you see in my screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of a graphical app that can do that. If it helps at all, the terminal command that does what you want would be `ping 8.8.8.8 | while read i; do echo $(date): $i; done`